# How to select not-wellformed data

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a huge table I'm trying to port to a new database, there's a row that stores number of doors, body style, and gearbox like "4SDa" for 4 door sedan, auto or "5HBm" for 5 door hatchback, manual.

I need to select all rows that AREN'T like this so I can edit them as they are causing issues.

How can I select any row that isn't in the format

```
number-letter-letter-letter' (case insensitive)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where your_column not regexp '^[0-9][a-zA-Z]{3,3}$'
```

### [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%5B0-9%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B3%2C3%7D%24&input=5HBm)

Comment: `REGEXP` is not case sensitive, so you don't need `A-Z` part.

Comment: works beautifully :) I'm sure I tried something like that... maybe it's just too late at night

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '4SDa'  REGEXP '^[0-9][a-z]{3}$';  --> 1
SELECT '4SDaa' REGEXP '^[0-9][a-z]{3}$';  --> 0
SELECT 'AAbb'  REGEXP '^[0-9][a-z]{3}$';  --> 0
```